# Ring $x^2=x$ then $2x=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups

If in a ring $R$, $x^2=x$ for all $x$ then show that $2x=0$ and $x+y=0 \Rightarrow x=y.$

I am unable to proceed. Plz help.

Comment: If you can square elements then you can square algebraic expressions.

Comment: Does "Ring" here necessarily include an identity?

Comment: No, it doesn't include an identity here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $(2x)^2=4x^2=4x$, and $(2x)^2=2x$, we have $4x=2x \Leftrightarrow 2x=0$.

Next $2x=0 \Leftrightarrow x+x=0 \Leftrightarrow x=-x$.

Finally $x+y = 0 \Leftrightarrow x-y=0 \Leftrightarrow x=y$.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that $2x = x+x$, $4x = 2x + 2x = x + x + x + x$ etc..:

Using that every element of $R$ equals its square:

$$2x = (2x)^2 = (x+x)(x+x) = x^2 + x^2 + x^2 + x^2 = 4x^2 = 4x = 2x +2x\text{.}$$
Substract $2x$ from both sides.

This means $2x = 0$, so $x + x = 0$ for all $x$, so $x$ is its own additive inverse, and so if $x + y = 0$, add $x$ to both sides...

Answer (score -1):

One has

$$\forall x\in A,\,(x+1_A)^2=x^2+x+x+1_A=x+1_A$$

and therefore $2x=x+x=0$

This immediately gives $0=x+y=x+y-2y=x-y$ and therefore $x=y$

If one does not assume a unit

$$(x+x)^2=x^2+2x^2+x^2=4x=2x$$

and therefore $2x=0$

Comment: I thought the OP said not to assume a unit?